# gcc: error: /e:/source codes/C/Practice/helloWorld.c: Invalid argument

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, visual-studio-code

my simple c program is not compiling in microsoft visual studio. when i run it, i get a error stating:-

gcc: fatal error: no input files

I used the extension "C Compiler" by brapifra (brapifra.c-compiler) [Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vbEU.png)

Comment: There is no problem in your code. Mostly compiler setting issue

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

This tells that you might be in a wrong directory. Just check the path you are providing for the build.
Also, provide more details related to the task file you created